# cannot play a mp4 file located in the assets folder

Tags: android, android-intent

Lots of people of have had issues playing a media file located in the assets folder. I looked at all the threads and none of them are conclusive. While all of them say it should be possible to play the media file, none of them gives a full solution.

This is what i am trying to attempt.

I have a mp4 file in the assets folder.

I wish to launch a GALLERY or any other intent that can play the mp4 file. I do not wish to have a videoview and/or a mediaplayer object inside my application.

Is this possible to do?

There were some threads that recommended moving the media file from assets folder into the res/raw folder. I tried that without any luck.

Firstly, this is what i did with the media file in the assets folder. The media file is named sample.mp4

```
String movieUrl = "file:///android_asset/sample.mp4";
// i even tried: String movieUrl = "file:///android_asset/sample";
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(movieUrl), "video/*");
startActivity(intent);
```

Secondly, i moved the sample.mp4 to the res/raw folder -

```
String movieUrl = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/raw/" + "sample.mp4";
// i even tried: String movieUrl = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/raw/" + "sample";
// i even tried: String movieUrl = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + R.raw.sample;
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(movieUrl), "video/*");
startActivity(intent);
```

Neither approach worked.
In the first case, i see the option to launch to the GALLERY intent. But as soon as pick a player from the list of options, i see the error

```
E/MediaPlayer(1642): Error (1,-2147483648)
```

In the second case, i see the following error rightaway:
    android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=android.resource://com.postureco.posturescreen/raw/2130968576 typ=video/* }

Surprisingly, if i place the sample.mp4 in the SD card and try the following code, everything works very well - I am able to launch the gallery app and have the file play there.

```
File file = new File("/sdcard/sample.mp4")
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "video/*");
startActivity(intent);
```

My Manifest permissions:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" android:required="false" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" android:required="false" />
```

Any inputs highly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: I am aware of the content-provider and content-resolver classes. But i 
have seen it being used only for sharing the application's database 
with other apps. Even if i created a content-provider for this video 
file, i am not sure how to consume it i.e be able to launch an intent 
and provide the video file as data to the 3rd party app.

Comment: @Dirk Are you able to get it to work?  I am also having the same issue.